# How much amount of data can be store in MyISAM DB?

Tags: mysql, myisam

How much amount of data can be store in MyISAM DB?
Can you Guys Says How Much TB?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A lot within these limits:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/limits.html

Also from manual

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/myisam-storage-engine.html

> There is a limit of 2^32 (~4.295E+09) rows in a MyISAM table. If you build MySQL with the --with-big-tables  option, the row limitation is increased to (2^32)^2  (1.844E+19) rows. See Section 2.17.2, “Typical configure Options”. Binary distributions for Unix and Linux are built with this option.

Just for fun: You can have 65536 bytes per row. This means you can create 5461 LONGTEXT/LONGBLOB columns, each able to store 4GB of data. Now multiply that times 2^64...

That's strictly theoretical number though.